# Amazon SNS web notification for browser

Tags: browser, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to implement Browser Notifications. Below is my requirement.

When user opens my website than he should receive alert to subscribe to push notifications.

If he chooses to allow it than I want to send him browser push notification whenever I am publishing data on my site.

Is this possible with AMAZON SNS or Any other better approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SNS doesn't support browser notification, as an alternative you can use Firebase which support web and mobile notifications

you can find more details here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: "Amazon SNS doesn't support browser notification" -> Any reference?

Answer (score 1):

AWS now has a new service AppSync and it can be used to build real time communication - https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/

Answer (score 0):

I got a task from my supervisor to send notification from AWS SNS using just an API endpoint. The endpoint is written in PHP.

I was able to send notification using that API written in PHP in purely the open-source way.

Web Push Notification using ServiceWorker makes me achieve this.

Here are the steps which I did:

*In that PHP API, I have a Guzzle HTTP Client which calls the NodeJS server to send push notification
*After sending push notification in NodeJS back-end, ServiceWorker will listen to that event
*ServiceWorker will show notification to my front-end

Answer (score 0):

can share code example

*In that PHP API, I have a Guzzle HTTP Client which calls the NodeJS server to send push notification *After sending push notification in NodeJS back-end, ServiceWorker will listen to that event *ServiceWorker will show notification to my front-end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is exacltly the same content as Felix Labayen provided.